# How do I have two functions on one HTML page that are called at different times using different elements?

Tags: javascript

Like the title says, I'm trying to have two functions that are called at different times, using an onlclick evenst on two different images. Essentially, my goal looks something like this:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function firstFunction(){
            does something
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function secondFunction(){
            does something different
        }
    </script>
    <img src = "..." onclick = "firstFunction()">
    <img src = "..." onclick = "secondFunction()">
</body>
```

I've tried this:

```
<body onload = "firstFunction(); secondFunction()">
```

However that didn't work and I can only seem to find info on calling two functions using the same onclick event on a single element so if someone knows how to solve this problem, that would be very helpful. Thanks.

The entire document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>TBD | Issue #1</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = ../comic-website-styles.css>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class = "main-header clearfix">
            <h1>TBD</h1>
            <nav class  = "main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = index.html>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = issues.html>Issues</a></li>
                    <li><a href = characters.html>Characters</a></li>
                    <li><a href = about.html>About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section class = "comic-reader">
            <img id = "left-page" src = "../issue-images/issue1/page1.png" onclick = "flipBackward()">
            <img id = "right-page" src = "../issue-images/issue1/page2.png" onclick= "flipForward()">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src = "flip-page.js"></script>
        <script>
            function flipForward(){
                var leftPage = document.getElementById("left-page");
                var rightPage = document.getElementById("right-page");

                //Going Forward
                if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page2.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page3.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page4.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page4.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page5.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page6.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page6.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page7.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page8.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page8.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page9.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page10.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page10.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page11.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page12.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page12.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page13.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page14.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page14.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page15.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page16.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page16.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page17.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page18.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page18.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page19.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page20.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page20.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page21.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page22.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page22.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page23.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page24.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page24.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page25.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page26.png"
                }
                else if(rightPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page26.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page27.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page28.png"
                }
                else {

                }
            }
            function flipBackward(){
                //Going Backward
                if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page3.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page1.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page2.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page5.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page3.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page4.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page7.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page5.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page6.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page9.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page7.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page8.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page11.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page9.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page10.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page13.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page11.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page12.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page15.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page13.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page14.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page17.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page15.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page16.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page19.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page17.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page18.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page21.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page19.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page20.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page23.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page21.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page22.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page25.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page23.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page24.png";
                }
                else if(leftPage.getAttribute('src') == "../issue-images/issue1/page27.png"){
                    leftPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page25.png";
                    rightPage.src = "../issue-images/issue1/page26.png";
                }
                else {

                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are these two independent functions? Do you want one function to occur when one image is clicked and another function when the other image is clicked?

Comment: your first code block should work ... what makes you think it doesn't - note, you don't need to put the two functions in separate script tags

Comment: ecg8 - that's precisely want I want.

Comment: @MatchesMalone - that's exactly what your code does - what is the problem?

Comment: That's what it should do but for some reason, the second function never executes.

Comment: browsers have **developer tool** - usually F12 - what errors appear in the dev tool **console**?

Comment: @Jaromanda X - I have these:                                                         
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND,          
   Uncaught ReferenceError: leftPage is not defined/ Sorry it's not a screenshot. My printscreen key is broken.

Comment: well, you'll need to fix that - though it has nothing to do with the code you posted - the code you posted, is it accurate?

Comment: @Jaromanda - Accurate as in the exact code I'm using or a representation of the code? I'm guessing you're talking about the former of the two, in which case, no. I didn't post the actual code I'm using because it's about 100 lines and last time I posted something that long, I got downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: Try this: 1) put all your code in one script block 2) move the script block to the bottom of the body  3) remove the body onload script. Does that work? if not, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: @ecg8 - 1) not necessary (but yes, you're right), 2) not necessary, and 3) thought that was something OP tried, not really the code he's looking at ... errors he says is about "file not found" - though, that would mean the img is not found - hardly a showstopper for javascript

Comment: @ecg8 - I'm afraid it didn't work. Would you mind if I showed you the entire document (It's only about 150 lines.) because I'm not entirely sure that the problem is what I think it is? See, I'm using a bunch of if statements and I've realized that they may be contradicting each other but then again maybe they're not. If you could just take a quick look, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, why not..

Comment: Wait, really? I'm not sure if you're being sarcastic or not. Usually I'd be murdered if I asked a question like that.

Comment: I'm not promising anything, but I'll look at it if you put it somewhere. Doesn't need to be here. Could be a codepen or JSfiddle or something.

Comment: @ecg8 - I added it to the question.

Comment: I'm looking at it now... You may want to look into switch...case in the future...

Comment: But is it because the if statements are indeed contradictory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and made a smaller example on JSFiddle. If you click the right image, both images get slightly bigger and if you click the left one, both images get slightly smaller.
https://jsfiddle.net/t3239vqm/19/

Two big things I saw in your code:
1)  you only declared leftPage and rightPage in your first function, so they were not available to your second function.
2)  there were some semicolons that you did not add in the first function
3)  you had a really long and nested if...else statement that I changed into a switch...case

This should be a good example to apply to your code.
HTML

```
<header class = "main-header clearfix">
  <h1>TBD</h1>
  <nav class  = "main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href = index.html>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href = issues.html>Issues</a></li>
      <li><a href = characters.html>Characters</a></li>
      <li><a href = about.html>About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class = "comic-reader">
  <img id = "left-page" src = "https://placehold.it/100x100" onclick = "flipBackward()">
  <img id = "right-page" src = "https://placehold.it/100x100" onclick= "flipForward()">
</section>
```

JS

```
function flipForward() {
  var leftPage = document.getElementById("left-page");
  var rightPage = document.getElementById("right-page");
  switch (rightPage.src) {
    case "https://placehold.it/100x100":
      leftPage.src = "https://placehold.it/110x110";
      rightPage.src = "https://placehold.it/110x110";
      break;
    case "https://placehold.it/110x110":
      leftPage.src = "https://placehold.it/120x120";
      rightPage.src = "https://placehold.it/120x120";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function flipBackward() {
  var leftPage = document.getElementById("left-page");
  var rightPage = document.getElementById("right-page");
  switch (leftPage.src) {
    case "https://placehold.it/120x120":
      leftPage.src = "https://placehold.it/110x110";
      rightPage.src = "https://placehold.it/110x110";
      break;
    case "https://placehold.it/110x110":
      leftPage.src = "https://placehold.it/100x100";
      rightPage.src = "https://placehold.it/100x100";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first observation was actually the issue. I'm actually really sorry for wasting the last hour of your life over something so stupid that I completely overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>
        <img src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/0.jpg?w=371" style="border:1px solid red" onclick="myfun1()"> 
        <img src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/1.jpg?w=371" style="border:1px solid red" onclick="myfun2()"> 
</body>
<script>
    function myfun1(){
        alert('You have clicked image 0')
    }
    function myfun2(){
        alert('You have clicked image 1')
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: But I need the image to change when it's clicked.

Comment: you can do that just access the src attribute of image and replace that with new image link.